# Penalty for comments for being rude or abusive when someone point out mistake

Tags: feature-request, comments, reputation, offensive

I have gone through this question: *[Can we add a reputation penalty to comments that are removed for being Rude or Abusive?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302019/can-we-add-a-reputation-penalty-to-comments-that-are-removed-for-being-rude-or-a)*

My concern is if a comment is removed for being rude or abusive, there should some penalty for people so they won't violate this being nice policy.

Here the scenario is: This user just copied the whole code from the first answer and just changed a few lines of those which will cause a `NullPointerException` to the OP. This will misguide OP and waste his time. When I tried to ask him for the same he became rude and edited his answer as he knew he was wrong. He should be thankful for pointing out his major issue of code. What he did was rude.

I pointed out that he was not giving the right information. But now I feel it's better to keep quiet and stay away from a user like this.

[image]

From the image we can see that I was pointing in the right direction. My intention is give the right information to the OP.

[image]

Comment: You did *half* of your duty - you downvoted the answer.  I hope you flagged the comment for removal.

Comment: @Makoto but he downvoted my answers to take revenge

Comment: @Dipalishah all this can be solved by customing flagging for a moderator attention and explaining...

Comment: You really can't prove that.  Flag their comment and that'll be the end of this.  If serial voting is done against you, it will eventually be rolled back.

Comment: If he revenge-downvoted several of your answers, that is likely to be rolled back in an automated process which picks these kinds of things up.

Comment: Also _This user just copied whole code from the first answer and just changed few lines of those which will cause NullPointerException to the OP_. This sounds disturbingly like plagiarism...Unless the original code was provided by the asker.  Like I said, a moderator who responds to the flag would be able to judge that

Comment: I also believe it is important to remind users of the [Be Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy, as I have done for this user.

Comment: Seriously you think that redacting the user's name is going to make any difference.

Comment: @mega6382 maybe not, but in the act of dealing with wrongdoing you must do your best not to turn into a monster yourself. Unnecessarily putting people in the spotlight is in violation of the be nice policy too.

Comment: @mega6382, On meta we have respect for Free Hand Red Circle, and will respect the privacy provided here. Op took time to concealed those information.

Comment: @DragandDrop I am not saying it is not a good idea, i am just saying that it serves no purpose doing it this late after the post. I mean you can still get the original image from going to [edit history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/358973/revisions) or you can just post the first line of the answer in the [SO search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=so+you+listen+to+the+itemselectedevent) and find the said post and the user.

Comment: There is no offuscation when bringing something to meta. Even if Op didn't post picture and reformulate ever comment  to make a research impossible. You could have click on Op activity tab to see the list of his comments. Or go throught op all answer. I see those red line as a: "I know you can find it but I did great in the colouring process. This is enought to calm Meta angry mob"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the appropriate course of action is to flag the comments which are rude/abusive. If there are other problems occurring use the custom moderator flag to explain the situation.

A single downvote is impossible to prove it came from the user unless they admit it, you will have to brush it off.

> My Concern is If a comment is removed for being rude or abusive, there should some penalty for people so they won't violate this being nice policy.

This is already handled by moderators. If there is a pattern or if the case requires it moderators can suspend the user account or impose a rep penalty on the user.